# Achieving at least 0.05 R-squared value

Tags: statistics

I got a dataset in Excel containing 1500 rows of data. There are 8 columns, "zone" is the independent variable and "SG_Frac" is the dependent variable. I need to remove the outliers  to achieve an r-squared value of at least 0.50. At least 500 points/number of observations should be retained. I keep on getting an error in my code in R.

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18c6lu5qJ2bNXaGmGkFgKA_Sk7Mrd_eaA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106521022893045257926&rtpof=true&sd=true) the file.

Here's my attempt:

```
df <- read_excel("C:/Users/data.xlsx")

df <- na.omit(df)

z_scores <- scale(df$SG_Frac)

df_no_outliers <- df[abs(z_scores) <= 3,]

model <- lm(SG_Frac ~ zone, data = df_no_outliers)

rsq <- summary(model)$r.squared

while (rsq < 0.50 | nrow(df_no_outliers) < 500) {

    z_scores <- scale(df$SG_Frac)

    df_no_outliers <- df[abs(z_scores) <= 2.5,]

    model <- lm(SG_Frac ~ zone, data = df_no_outliers)

    rsq <- summary(model)$r.squared
}
```